# unable to load json data

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am unable to load the json data & getting errors which mention below.
My code is ,

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://172.28.1.220//actifio/api/info/lsjobhistory?sessionid=cafc8f31-fb39-4020-8172-e8f0085004fd'

ret=requests.get(url,verify=False)
data=json.load(ret)

print(data)
```

**Getting error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pr.py", line 7, in <module>
    data=json.load(ret)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: `ret` is a response object, not the response data - you probably want to do something like `json.load(ret.data)`

Comment: @match it's `ret.text` (cf requests doc), and then you want `json.loads()`, not `json.load()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont actually need to `import json`

try this

```
import requests

url = 'https://172.28.1.220//actifio/api/info/lsjobhistory?sessionid=cafc8f31-fb39-4020-8172-e8f0085004fd'

ret = requests.get(url,verify=False)
data = ret.json()

print(data)
```

Comment: For further reading: [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content)

Comment: Yes this is working, in that entire json data I want below two.

1)All "sourceid"
2)All information about one "sourceid"

Comment: @PradeepAvula, I'm sorry, I don't quite understand. This is not what you wanted? 
If you need to do something further, please provide a bit of json and data you want to extract. Cheers

Comment: {'sourceid': 'Image_0291405a', 'originatinguds': '1415043714', 'retrycount': '0', 'queuedate': '2018-12-10 11:20:35.804', 'flags': '16', 'sltname': 'Every20minutes', 'jobclass': 'cleanup', 'startdate': '2018-12-10 11:20:35.804', 'priority': '', 'sourceuds': '1415043714', 'jobtag': '', 'hostname': 'ACC-CLUSTER.CSE.LOCAL', 'targethost': '', 'appname': 'ACC-INSTANCE0\\INSTANCE0' , 'id': '298287', 'jobname': 'Job_0298281', 'consistencydate': '2018-12-10 11:20:35.804', 'status': 'failed'}

is the json data, simlary I have 100 lists. I just want only sourceid of all

Comment: You can try:
sourceIds = [] 
for element in data:
    sourceIds.append(element['sourceid'])

Should work if i understand correctly

Comment: import requests

url = 'https://172.28.1.220//actifio/api/info/lsjobhistory?sessionid=cafc8f31-fb39-4020-8172-e8f0085004fd'

ret = requests.get(url,verify=False)
data = ret.json()

#print(data)
print(data['result'][1]['sourceid'])


This worked fine but I want all the list instead of 1st list